# Where to create ArcGIS 10 Map Templates?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcgis-desktop

Sorry, I could not find the location: C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcMap\Templates

Do I create it or there is a specific funtionality for the location?

I would like to create different templates for the areas we mostly use the maps.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a 3 year old Question from a user who has not logged in for 18 months and the Comments and unaccepted Answers suggest problem was probably resolved long ago

Answer (score 4):

2 things you might be doing wrong here.

Firstly - the above path is for a Windows 7/Vista/Windowse Server 2008 OS.  If your on XP, the path will be in your documents&settings/username/(etc)

But I also spot your path does not actually have a username in it.
Between Users and AppData, you should have the folder that is the profile that you installed and use ArcGIS Desktop with (i.e. the profile you login to Windows with)

Third thing (which user found out them self) is that by default, the AppData folder is a hidden folder in all Windows Operating Systems.  In the file/folder properties settings, you can choose to show these.

Comment: Tks Simon. I realized that the folder "AppData" was hidden.
I have just made it visible and was able to see it.
By the way, I am using Windows 7, and the user name is also there (ecomuana) before the path "AppData".

Let me se if from here I can achieve my objective.

Comment: I'm not sure about Windows7/Vista, but in XP, I can enter `%userprofile%`(a windows environment variable) into my explorer address box and hit enter and it will put you at your profile.  So pasting in `%userprofile%\Application Data\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcMap\Templates` should put you at your template directory.

Answer (score 2):

There's an excellent document on the WebHelp that describes options for where to store *.mxd files that you want to be recognized as Map Templates (including multiple System template locations) at http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/00s9/00s90000002w000000.htm